# Recurring decimal within an aligned array

Tags: amsmath, siunitx, arrays, alignment

I am having some issues with representing recurring decimals (using `\overline{}`) within an aligned array I am using to represent a matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
    \left[
        \begin{array}{@{}R{3.6}R{3.6}|R{3.4@{}}}
            1 &0 &=\SI[parse-numbers=false]{61.\overline{36}}{}\\
            0 &0.228096 &8.8128\\
        \end{array}
    \right]
    &R_2 \rightarrow \frac{R_2}{0.228096}\\
    \left[
        \begin{array}{@{}R{3.6}R{3.6}|R{3.4@{}}}
            1 &0 &=\SI[parse-numbers=false]{61.\overline{36}}{}\\
            0 &1 &38.63\\
        \end{array}
    \right]
\end{aligned}
\]    
\end{document}
```

Using just `\overline{36}` causes the number to overlap the right bracket
The code snippet above works, with some errors in alignment of the recurring decimal; however, if I change:

`0 &1 &38.63\\`

to

`0 &1 &=\SI[parse-numbers=false]{38.\overline{63}}{}\\`

It breaks the last matrix with the left alignment moving and both recurring decimals overlapping the right bracket.

How can I add recurring decimals to the `61.36` and `38.63` without breaking my alignment?

Also, for my understanding, could someone please explain to me what is happening that is causing the final matrix to break?

Comment: Off-topic: `\begin{array}{@{}R{3.6}R{3.6}|R{3.4@{}}}` cannot be correct. You should probably write `\begin{array}{@{}R{3.6}R{3.6}|R{3.4}@{}}`.

Comment: If you want to typeset numbers without scientific units, don't employ `\SI`. Instead, use `\num`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-comparators}  % new

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
    \left[
        \begin{array}{ @{} R{3.6}R{3.6} | S[table-format=4.6,         % changed
                                            parse-numbers=false] @{}} % new
            1 & 0        & = 61.\overline{36} \\                      % changed
            0 & 0.228096 &    8.8128
        \end{array}
    \right]
    &R_2 \rightarrow \frac{R_2}{0.228096}\\
    \left[
        \begin{array}{ @{} R{3.6}R{3.6} | S[table-format=4.6,
                                            parse-numbers=false] @{}}
            1 & 0        & = 61.\overline{36} \\
            0 & 1        &   38.63
        \end{array}
    \right]
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```